# PHP HTML data format

Tags: php, html, symfony

How to process this type of input form:

```
<form action="update" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="people[][firstname]" value="John" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="people[][surname]" value="Smith" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="people[][firstname]" value="Adam" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="people[][surname]" value="Boralsky" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

I would expect to receive a multidimensional array, but instead I am receiving this:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'firstname' => string 'John' (length=4)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'surname' => string 'Smith' (length=5)
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      'firstname' => string 'Adam' (length=4)
  3 => 
    array (size=1)
      'surname' => string 'Boralsky' (length=8)
```

Has anybody seen this sort of format?

Comment: put an index instead `people[0][firstname]`, `people[0][surname]` and so on,,

Comment: It seems to be a PHP array. Where are you receiving this? How are you printing this array? How are you trying to access this values inside the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's happening because that's actually what you're asking PHP to do. [] is the "next array index" operator, so when PHP processes the input, it sees `people[][firstname] = John`, understands that as "Add to $people[] = ['firstname' => 'John']", and you get:

```
$people = [
    ['firstname' => 'John'],
];
```

Then, when we get `people[][surname] = Smith`, "add to $people[] = ['surname' => 'Smith']". Which then gives us:

```
$people = [
    ['firstname' => 'John'],
    ['Surname' => 'Smith'],
];
```

and so on.

What you'll need to do is explicitly set an array key in your html. If this is the only person in the form, then instead of `people[]`, use `people[0]`. If there are multiple people, then you're going to have to dynamically generate an index for each field common to a person.

Comment: Winner winner! Well written sir.